# How to use geom_smooth() on data that is different from the actual plotted data?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a line graph using ggplot2 with three lines (with variable names, say, 'A', 'B' and 'C' in my data frame). I want to add a geom_smooth using `method=loess`, but I want to add the regression line based on the minimum of 'B' and 'C'. Is there a way to do this?

To illustrate, here's a mock code:

```
names  <- c('n1', 'n2', 'n3', 'n4', 'n5')
aline  <- c(0.18, 0.21, 0.23, 0.20, 0.16)
bline  <- c(0.50, 0.40, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10)
cline  <- c(0.14, 0.20, 0.30, 0.35, 0.33)
min_bc <- c(0.14, 0.20, 0.30, 0.20, 0.10)
df <- data.frame(name, aline, bline, cline)
df.m <- melt(df)
g <- ggplot(df.m, aes(group=1, names, value, colour=variable))
g <- g + geom_line(aes(group=variable))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(colour=variable), alpha=0.4)
```

I want to add a regression line using `aline` and `min_bc`, without actually plotting `min_bc`.

Additionally, I would like to throw this in:
In general, I may have some data, and I want to want to plot (in the same graph) different lines (or points, bars, etc.) using different transformations of the data. Is there any comprehensive document where I can get the broad picture of how to do such things in R/ggplot?

Comment: This is a little confusing. You mean you want to plot the regression line from `aline ~ min_bc` (or maybe the reverse)?

Comment: Change the `data` and `aes(x=..., y=...)` arguments within any ggplot object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, one sets the dataset relevant for a plot in the main call to `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(data, aes()) + geom_point()
```

However, you can also set the dataset individually for the `geom`:

```
ggplot(data1, aes()) + geom_point(data = data2)
```

Using this technique, you can precompute the dataset off which you want to plot the LOESS, and feed that to `geom_smooth()`. The following example confirms this hypothesis:

```
df1 = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = runif(100))
df2 = data.frame(x = 1:100, y = runif(100) + 1)
ggplot(df1, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(data = df2)
```

[image]

In this example, both datasets have the same column names. If this is not the case, you need to also tweak the `aes` setting within `geom_smooth`.

Do keep in mind that plotting a smoothing of another dataset than the one you plot beneath it could make things very unclear.

Comment: I have another doubt on the topic...  How to consider two different dataframes, where the one used in the ggplot has an object not present in the second (the dataframe used to create the geom_smooth). If both don't have all exact objects, it will fail.